# Help emailing short videos from iPhoto

Tags: macos

I uploaded short videos taken w/iPhone 4S (IOS7) to iPhoto on my iMac 10.7.5 "Lion"

I want to email them to my family but iPhoto will NOT allow videos.

Must I put all my videos into iTunes or iMovie? I don't know how to use iMovie.

Any help will be appreciated,

Ingrid Phillips
ingy59@gmail.com

Comment: Confusing! So you made a video with iPhone. Then you uplodaded? to your iMac. Now you want to email that video, but you found out that the iPhoto will not play it. Why are you using iPhoto in all this?

Comment: When you check the video file what does it say after the DOT (.)

Comment: Videos came from iPhone 4S & in iPhoto "info" it shows29.97 fps (1920 x 1080 177 MB video camera image then H.264

Comment: Why? Because I did NOT know iPhoto is wrong place for short videos. So, what do you suggest as I've deleted the videos from my iPhone 4S?

Comment: No problem, next time you know. Now follow the instructions in my answer please.

Answer (score 1):

Since you uploaded the video using iPhoto they are in the iPhoto library on your Mac.

To show you where, select the video in iPhoto, now click on the File in menu bar and select show in Finder.

That will show you where the Video is on your disk.

Go to it and right click selecting share by email **BUT**:

The file is 177 MB (to large to send by email), so you need to upload it to the web (like your Google drive..ect..) a place where you family can access to down load.